# Bug in .NET parsing XML with inline XDR schema?

Tags: .net, xml, field-device-tool, xdr-schema

We had an XML causing an XMLSchemaException when validating in .NET. Validating the same XML with MSXML is fine and does not result in an error.

The XML document is using XDR inline schemas as required by the underlying FDT technology, so I can't use DTD or W3C schemas and I have to stick to the old and obsolete XDR validation.

I have minimized it to the following SSCCE so you can try yourself. Also available on [dotNetFiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/AquCnh):

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace XDRInlineReferenceInline
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static string xml =
            @"<Root xmlns:dt=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes"" xmlns:s=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-data"">
  <s:Schema name=""InlineA"">
    <s:AttributeType name=""att"" dt:type=""ui1"" />
  </s:Schema>
  <s:Schema name=""InlineB"" xmlns:a=""x-schema:#InlineA"">
    <s:ElementType name=""Ele"" content=""empty"" model=""closed"">
      <s:attribute type=""a:att"" required=""yes"" />
    </s:ElementType>
  </s:Schema>
  <Ele xmlns=""x-schema:#InlineB"" xmlns:a=""x-schema:#InlineA"" a:att=""1"" />
</Root>";

        public static void Main()
        {
            var textReader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xml));
            var validatingReader = new XmlValidatingReader(textReader) {ValidationType = ValidationType.XDR};
            var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(validatingReader);
        }
    }
}
```

**Is this a bug of the .NET parser or is there anything I could change to make it work?**

I have tried changing the order of schemas within the XML document, but that does not help.

Please do not suggest combining the two different schemas into one. I have tried that and it works, but unfortunately it's not an option. As the schema name serves as a namespace at the same time, XPaths of all existing products would need to be changed.

Comment: `[ObsoleteAttribute("Use XmlReader created by XmlReader.Create() method using appropriate XmlReaderSettings instead. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202")]`

Comment: So, why is it not an option to combine the schemas?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I tried XmlReader.Create(), but it won't find problems, even if I add bigger mistakes. ValidationType.XDR on XmlReaderSettings is also obsolete.

Comment: I don't know if it supports XDR schemas. In fact, I don't know that .NET still supports XDR at all.

Comment: For the curious: I already tried refactoring the code to get rid of the warnings, but I failed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723218/refactoring-xmlschemacollection-xmlvalidatingreader-and-validationtype-xdr-to-g

Comment: The warnings aren't the problem. .NET support for XDR is the real problem. Use of a technology that requires XDR is a problem.